# C: Output consists of question marks?

Tags: c, arrays, input, output, strtok

**EDIT, figured it out. New code is as follows:**

```
  void add_card_to_rolodex(card *card_array)
{       
        card newcard = {"", "", ""};
        char newuser[250];
        scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", newuser);
        strcat(newuser, "\n");
        newcard.last_name = strdup(strtok(newuser, " "));
        newcard.first_name = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
        newcard.phone_number = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));

        card_array[size] = newcard;
        size++;

}
```

**Old code:**

```
void add_card_to_rolodex(card *card_array)
{
        //Function asks for input and adds it to the passed array
        //card is a struct of char *
        card *newcard = malloc(sizeof(newcard));
        char newuser[250];
        scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", newuser);
        strcat(newuser, "\n");

        newcard->last_name = strdup(strtok(newuser, " "));
        newcard->first_name = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
        newcard->phone_number = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));

        //size is global
        card_array[size] = *newcard;
        size++;
        free(newcard);

}
```

**I am attempting to add to the end of a file, that was previously read into an array.
This is the original output, before this function is called.**

...

81 Velez Ingrid (648)685-8104

82 Warren Buffy (570)247-2921

83 Watson Vera (640)276-5047

84 Whitehead Wayne (681)747-8152

85 Winters Damian (790)348-2599

86 York Keith (592)276-6850

87 Zamora Dean (281)906-9590

**Lets say I call the function 3 times with my input as:**

Bob Jones 818

Jim J 616

Foo Bar 123

**When I print the array again I get:**

81 Velez Ingrid (648)685-8104

82 Warren Buffy (570)247-2921

83 Watson Vera (640)276-5047

84 Whitehead Wayne (681)747-8152

85 Winters Damian (790)348-2599

86 York Keith (592)276-6850

87 Zamora Dean (281)906-9590

88 ?J?I? Jones 818

89 Jim Jones 616

90 Foo Bar 123

**As you can see, on line 88, the output starts with ?J?I?...All of the following inputs are fine.
I read that it has to do with unreadable values, but I'm fairly lost as to what is happening otherwise! I'm fairly new to C, and any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 2):

```
card *newcard = malloc(sizeof(newcard));
```

only allocates 4 bytes - size of the pointer

it should be:

```
card *newcard = malloc(sizeof(*newcard));
```

Answer (score 0):

The name is overwritten because the buffer allocated for newcard was too small.  See the answer below.

unrelated, if you're only reading the words out of the newuser buffer, there is no point to newline terminating the string

also, when freeing a struct of strings, each string should be freed as well to not leak memory

Edit: my original point was wrong, these are minor.

Comment: That is not correct. `card_type` is declared as `card *card_array`.

Comment: oops, right you are.  I edited it out (I originally confused card * with card **).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to use heap memory for `newcard`. You can just use:

```
void add_card_to_rolodex(card *card_array)
{
    //Function asks for input and adds it to the passed array
    //card is a struct of char *
    card newcard;
    char newuser[250];
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", newuser);
    strcat(newuser, "\n");

    newcard.last_name = strdup(strtok(newuser, " "));
    newcard.first_name = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
    newcard.phone_number = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));

    //size is global
    card_array[size] = newcard;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just figured that out! Perfect.

Comment: @user3566141, saw your edit after I posted this answer.